# calculator equal button c#

Tags: c#, button, calculator, equals

I have a problem that I want to solve but I don't know how. I made a simple calculator with only a few buttons (Button 1, Button 5, Button+ and Button Equals). I want to make Button Equal repeat the last operation(in this case addition). It works fine when I press 5 + 1 and get the result 6,  but after that, when I press Button Equal again, I don't get result 7 but I get 12. 
I simply don't know where my mistake is and how to make that repeat function and without adding another button.

I hope someone replies soon and helps my problem. :)

```
    string input = string.Empty;
    string oper1 = string.Empty;
    string oper2 = string.Empty;
    char operacija;
    double rezultat = 0.0;
    bool rez = false;
    bool repeating= false; 

    private void buttonNumber1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBoxPrikazi.Text = "";
        if (rez)
        {
            input = "1";
            rez = false;
        }
        else
        {
            input += "1";
        }

        this.textBoxPrikazi.Text += input;
    }

    private void buttonNumber5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBoxPrikazi.Text = "";
        if (rez)
        {
            input = "5";
            rez = false;
        }
        else
        {
            input += "5";
        }

        this.textBoxPrikazi.Text += input;
    }

    private void buttonPlus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBoxPrikazi.Text = "+";
        oper1 = input;
        operacija = '+';
        input = string.Empty;
    }

    private void buttonEquals_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        oper2 = input;
        double num1, num2;
        double.TryParse(oper1, out num1);
        double.TryParse(oper2, out num2);



        this.textBoxPrikazi.Text = "0";
        this.input = string.Empty;
        this.oper1 = string.Empty;
        this.oper2 = string.Empty;


        if (operacija == '+')
        {
            // x =       1 +    5 
            rezultat = num1 + num2;
            textBoxPrikazi.Text = rezultat.ToString();

            // for repeating
            if (repeating== true)
            {
                // 6      =    6  
                rezultat = num2;
                //  6+      6    = 12
                textBoxPrikazi.Text = (rezultat + num2).ToString();
                repeating= false;

            }

        }

        if (rezultat == 0)
        {
            textBoxPrikazi.Text = "0";
        }
        else
        {
            input = rezultat.ToString();
            rez = true;
            repeating= true; // for repeating
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You need to read about `switch/case` block.

Comment: This is an opportune time to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger.  Using your debugger, place a breakpoint at the start of your "equals" operation and attempt the test again.  When the code "pauses" in debug mode, step through the execution of the code line by line.  Observe the runtime values and behavior.  Where in that operation does it first differ from what you were expecting?  What are the values at that time?  What were you expecting them to be or do?  Why?

Comment: This is because you keep your `rezultat` and `input` separate.

Comment: Also there is tons of calculator implementations in c# online, this would be valid if you're for example trying to learn `if/else` statement.

Comment: Thank you guys for your replies in such a short time. I am familiar with switch/case block. I am using switch/case in my other calculator where i have more operations like (+,*,-,/...etc). 
I watched tones of calculator videos but i could not find a good example, And none of those videos go that far to explain how to make equal button repeat its last function. From what i watched, they are all simple and basic calculators. 
Dasblinkenligh, what do u suggest ...that i dont separate them at all? what should i change?
David, thank for your reply. I will do as you said and will observe it.

Comment: `rezultat = num2;  textBoxPrikazi.Text = (rezultat + num2)`. So if num2 = 1, you show 1+1, whereas, if you want to show 7, you want to show the old result + num2. Simply removing `rezultat = num2` should fix your immediate problem, but not storing your result in your rzultat variable seems a good way to cause new problems in the near future.